# No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP using Spring SAML

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am trying to implement the Spring Security with SAML using the tutorial by @VladimírSchäfer i.e. [chapter-quick-start](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html)  however when I am downloading the sample project and deploying it I am getting the below error " No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP " ,

the detailed stack trace is as follows:

```
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.getDefaultIDP(MetadataManager.java:781)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.populatePeerEntityId(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.getLocalAndPeerEntity(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.commence(SAMLEntryPoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


my bean is configured as follows:

        <!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
        <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                    <property name="entityId" value="urn:test:KratiSukhmeen:Indorejaipur" />
                <!--    <property name="extendedMetadata">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                            <property name="signMetadata" value="false" />
                            <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                    </property> -->
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
```

I am relatively new to SAML can you please suggest where I am wrong?

Also I am not sure what values do I set in "urn:test:yourName:yourCity".Please elaborate on the same in detail.

Answer (score 0):

as shown in the quick start guide, you need to add the configuration for idp metadata in your spring security configuration :

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">5000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

then, depending on your idp's metadata location, you have to modify the url     `http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml`